# как установить качество в pytube

Tags: python, pytube

как установить качество скачиваемого видео в pytube

Comment: Посмотрите: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/f87a0266c2ae7920e2be6215fb3fd306ba2b5d09/pytube__examples/main.py#L20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы выбрать нужный `stream` для скачивания, Вы можете воспользоваться методами `filter` и `order_by`.

***Пример:***

```py
from pytube import YouTube

streams = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=...').streams


# Лучшее видео
streams.order_by('resolution').desc().first()

# Видео в FullHD
streams.filter(res='1080p').desc().first()

# Лучшее видео, имеющее аудиодорожку (до 720p)
streams.filter(progressive=True).desc().first()
```